# Upload and resize image

Tags: python, python-2.x, image, django

I have implemented following code to upload and resize image in Django. Please suggest ways to make it more pythonic.

```
def view(request, spot_id)
    IMAGE_DIR = MEDIA_ROOT + 'spot/' + spot_id        

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PublishedSpotForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data.copy()
            # dimension for logo 160x160 , 80x80, 64x64, 40x40
            # dimension for cover 800x600 , 600x480, 480x360, 200x150
            if 'logo' in request.FILES:
                logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=160,
                                                          height=160)
                logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=80, height=80)
                logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=64, height=64)
                logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=40, height=40)
                logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=None, height=None)
                if "logo" in cleaned_data:
                    cleaned_data.pop("logo")
                cleaned_data["logo"] = logo_path

            if 'cover' in request.FILES:
                cover_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'cover', request.FILES['cover'], width=None, height=None)
                cover_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'cover', request.FILES['cover'], width=800,
                                                           height=600)
                cover_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'cover', request.FILES['cover'], width=600,
                                                           height=480)
                cover_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'cover', request.FILES['cover'], width=480,
                                                           height=360)
                cover_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'cover', request.FILES['cover'], width=200,
                                                           height=150)
                if 'cover' in cleaned_data:
                    cleaned_data.pop('cover')
                cleaned_data['cover'] = cover_path
                       ...
```

The method for re-sizing an image:

```
def handle_uploaded_image(save_to, image_name, image_file, width=None, height=None):
    import os, hashlib
    import StringIO
    from django.core.files import File
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps

    # todo throw exception if path isn't available
    if not os.path.exists(save_to):
        os.makedirs(save_to)

    # read image from InMemoryUploadedFile
    str = ""
    for c in image_file.chunks():
        str += c

    # create PIL Image instance
    imagefile = StringIO.StringIO(str)
    image = Image.open(imagefile)

    if width is None or height is None:
        filename = image_name + '.jpg'
        imagefile = open(os.path.join(save_to, filename), 'w')
        image.save(imagefile, 'JPEG', quality=90)
        return True

    # if not RGB, convert
    if image.mode not in ("L", "RGB"):
        image = image.convert("RGB")

    # define file output dimensions (ex 60x60)

    # get orginal image ratio
    img_ratio = float(image.size[0]) / image.size[1]

    # resize but constrain proportions?
    if width == 0.0:
        width = height * img_ratio
    elif height == 0.0:
        height = width / img_ratio

    # output file ratio
    resize_ratio = float(width) / height
    width = int(width)
    height = int(height)

    # get output with and height to do the first crop
    if (img_ratio > resize_ratio):
        output_width = width * image.size[1] / height
        output_height = image.size[1]
        originX = image.size[0] / 2 - output_width / 2
        originY = 0
    else:
        output_width = image.size[0]
        output_height = height * image.size[0] / width
        originX = 0
        originY = image.size[1] / 2 - output_height / 2

    # crop
    cropBox = (originX, originY, originX + output_width, originY + output_height)
    image = image.crop(cropBox)

    # resize (doing a thumb)
    image.thumbnail([width, height], Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # re-initialize imageFile and set a hash (unique filename)
    filename = image_name + '_%dx%d.jpg' % (width, height)

    # save to disk
    imagefile = open(os.path.join(save_to, filename), 'w')
    image.save(imagefile, 'JPEG', quality=90)
    imagefile = open(os.path.join(save_to, filename), 'r')
    content = File(imagefile)

    return save_to
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments:

- Note that to overwrite a value in a dictionary you just need to set it, there's no need to pop the value out of the dictionary
- Follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

  - Instead of a line for set of dimensions use a loop
  - Instead of repeating for each file, use a function

With the suggested changes, the view code would be more or less as follows:

```
def view(request, spot_id):
    IMAGE_DIR = MEDIA_ROOT + 'spot/' + spot_id
    LOGO_DIMENSIONS = [(160, 160), (80, 80), (64, 64), (40, 40), (None, None)]
    COVER_DIMENSIONS = [(None, None), (800, 600), (600, 480), (480, 360), (200, 150)]

    def handle_uploaded_image_with_dimensions(name, dimensions):
        """Upload image with different dimensions."""
        if name in request.FILES:
            for width, height in dimensions:
                path = handle_uploaded_image(
                    IMAGE_DIR,
                    name,
                    request.FILES[name],
                    width=width,
                    height=height)
            cleaned_data[name] = path

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PublishedSpotForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data.copy()
            # dimension for logo 160x160 , 80x80, 64x64, 40x40
            # dimension for cover 800x600 , 600x480, 480x360, 200x150
            handle_uploaded_image_with_dimensions('logo', LOGO_DIMENSIONS)
            handle_uploaded_image_with_dimensions('cover', COVER_DIMENSIONS)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
IMAGE_DIR = MEDIA_ROOT + 'spot/' + spot_id
```

Use `os.path.join` to compose the path

Here:

```
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data.copy()
```

I don't think you really need to make a copy of `cleaned_data`... what's bad in modifying it?

Here:

```
            logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=160,
                                                      height=160)
            logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=80, height=80)
            logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=64, height=64)
            logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=40, height=40)
            logo_path = handle_uploaded_image(IMAGE_DIR, 'logo', request.FILES['logo'], width=None, height=None)
```

use iteration. Store your list of sizes and iterate over it. I would only leave apart the last case `(None,None)` because it is the only one of which you really use the return value (so, don't store the return value when you don't use it).

Here:

```
        if "logo" in cleaned_data:
            cleaned_data.pop("logo")
        cleaned_data["logo"] = logo_path
```

the `if` part can be skipped since the item will be anyway popped in the following line.

Here:

```
str = ""
for c in image_file.chunks():
    str += c
```

use `bytes` instead of `string`. The code will look more explicit and would be ready for python3.